# Is this script vulnerable to XSS? If yes, how can I exploit it?

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript

Is this script is vulnerable to XSS? If yes then how can I exploit it?

```
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
      var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-34064858-1'],['_trackPageview']];
      (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
      g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    //]]>
</script>
```

Here you can see `location`, I guess we can exploit it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last sentence? Where would you guess that the vulnerability is?

Comment: This is a standard Google Analytics tracking snippet used by a huge number of websites. It would be VERY bad if this were vulnerable, which it's almost certainly not.

Answer (score 4):

This does not look exploitable to me. The only user input here is the `location` variable. However, it is only used to check if the protocol is HTTPS or not and then change the URL of the included script accordingly. There is no way to sneak any parts of the URL, like a query parameter, into `g.src`. Also note how it is constructed through concatenating hard coded constants together.

So if you want to exploit this, you are out of luck.